# javascript error TypeError: scr is null http://widgets.amung.us/classic.js Line 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I AM GETTING THIS ERROR

TypeError: scr is null
http://widgets.amung.us/classic.js
Line 1

in firebug console, i am using wordpress with few basic plugins and a simple theme, I have searched all the templates but didn't find where it comes from,i need to find and fix it. Any body please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to help if you can post a URL to a live site so we can see what's actually going on. If not, if you can indicate what plugins, theme, etc. you're using.

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors on that page in Chrome console. Is it happening when you're trying a certain action or you're just seeing that error as soon as you load the page?

Comment: i found the cause of error, now need it removed. please follow this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982902/prevent-malware-javascript-from-executing